# Why window.performance.navigation.type === window.performance.navigation.TYPE_BACK_FORWARD is not always true when we click back button

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, browser, client

when we click the back button,

```
window.performance.navigation.type === window.performance.navigation.TYPE_BACK_FORWARD
```

is not always true and we have different behavior on different pages? what is it related to?

I was expecting that

```
window.performance.navigation.type === window.performance.navigation.TYPE_BACK_FORWARD
```

should always be true on clicking the back button in a web browser but it is not true? I am looking for the source of this issue.

Comment: It could be that the "Back" URL leads to a redirect. What is the type that you see? Also note that the API is deprecated and probably should not be used at all.

Comment: `Type_BACK_FORWARD` does not mean you have clicked the back button, it just mean you just navigated into the history. Check the documentation, and as Ponty comments, this is deprecated, so you should probably migrate it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigation